# ReferenceError state is not defined in vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My `vuex` store looks like this but when calling `addCustomer` I get `ReferenceError: state is not defined`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: { customers: [] },
  mutations: {
    addCustomer: function (customer) {
      state.customers.push(customer); // error is thrown here
    }
  }
});
```

This is the `addCustomer` binding/template:

```
<template>
    <button class="button" @click="addCustomer">Add Customer</button>
</template>
```

This is the definition for `addCustomer`:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "bootstrap",
    methods: {
      addCustomer: function() {
        const customer = {
          name: 'Some Name',
        };

        this.$store.commit('addCustomer', customer);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `state` in addCustomer function parameters (`addCustomer: function (customer)`) :

```
     import Vue from 'vue';
     import Vuex from 'vuex';

     Vue.use(Vuex);

     export default new Vuex.Store({
       state: { customers: [] },
       mutations: {
         addCustomer: function (state,customer) {
           state.customers.push(customer); // error is thrown here
         }
       }
     });
```