# Vuex state reset function undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, state, vuex

Getting `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getDefaultState is not defined`
when trying to use a store reset function on a module store. Nuxt documentation on store setup unfortunately is not very thoughrough. Can anyone point me to what I'm missing to make this available on the root level?
[image] [image]

My store reset is based on:
[Vuex issue 118](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1118)
The above is used [here with a state function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295340/how-to-clear-state-in-vuex-store)

My store setup is based on:
[Latest implementation, that I actually used](https://shouts.dev/how-to-reset-vuex-module-state)
Along with this [very well structured answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446792/nuxt-vuex-how-do-i-break-down-a-vuex-module-into-separate-files) by CMarzin

Framework documentations used:
[Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing)
and
[Nuxt store documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store)

Not related:
[This is about general store usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841842/referenceerror-state-is-not-defined-in-vuex-store/52841880)

My setup:

```
└── store
  └── user
    └── state.js
    └── getters.js
    └── mutations.js
    └── actions.js
 └── state.js (root state)
 └── getters.js (root getters)
 └── mutations.js (root mutations)
 └── actions.js (root actions)
```

`user/state.js`:

```js
const getDefaultState = () => {
  return {
    counter: 2,
    user: false,
  }
}

const state = getDefaultState()

export default {
  state,
}
```

`user/mutations.js`:

```js
export default {
  ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION: (state, { authUser, claims }) => {
    if (authUser) {
      const { uid, email, emailVerified, displayName, photoURL } = authUser
      state.user = { uid, email, emailVerified, displayName, photoURL }
    } else {
      state.user = false
    }
  },

  RESET_USER_STATE(state) {
    // Merge rather than replace so we don't lose observers
    // https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1118
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295340/how-to-clear-state-in-vuex-store
    console.log(state)
    Object.assign(state, getDefaultState())
  },
}
```

`user/actions.js`:

```js
export default {
  async onAuthStateChanged({ commit, dispatch }, { authUser }) {
    if (!authUser) {
      dispatch('resetUserState')
      return
    }
    if (authUser && authUser.getIdToken) {
      try {
        const idToken = await authUser.getIdToken(true)
        console.info('idToken', idToken)
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    }
    commit('ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION', { authUser })
  },

  resetUserState({ commit }) {
    commit('RESET_USER_STATE')
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `user/mutations.js` file you use the `getDefaultState()`-function, but you need to import it in order for the mutations to know what it is. In order to import it, you also have to export it.

So your `user/state.js` should be changed to this:

```
export const getDefaultState = () => {
  ...
}
```

And then if you change your `user/mutations.js` file:

```
import { getDefaultState } from './state.js'

export default {
  ...

  RESET_USER_STATE(state) {
    // Merge rather than replace so we don't lose observers
    // https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1118
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295340/how-to-clear-state-in-vuex-store
    console.log(state)
    Object.assign(state, getDefaultState())
  },
}
```

It should now work.

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj, I will try that. The reason I did not do this, is because I was under the impression that Nuxt takes care of this for me.I thought it assembles the store based on the present folder structure and combines all files in a folder to a module (aka `user/actions.js` + `user/mutations.js` + `user/state.js` + `user/getters.js` become `userModule` that gets added to the root store.

Is that thinking incorrect? If so it would reduce some of the benefit I get in terms of clarity by separating files.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly certain about how these particular files are handled by Nuxt. I reckon they're handled just like regular js files in modern bundlers such as webpack. In such module systems, each file is a module and modules are isolated, so only members exposed using `export` are available from outside the module. :-) I still believe you can use this approach, and I think it's still quite clear even when having to occasionally import and export.